# Do not trigger add event on adding a model to a collection

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way not to trigger add event when i am adding a new model to a collection by collection method add or push
Example:

```
collection.add({name: 'any name'})
```

I tried like giving

```
collection.add({name: 'xyz'}, {add: false})
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@idbehold has perfectly answered this. You can pass `{silent: true}` in the options to suppress the `add` event. I just want to add some information from the documentation. Read what it says

> Generally speaking, when calling a function that emits an event (model.set, collection.add, and so on...), if you'd like to prevent the event from being triggered, you may pass {silent: true} as an option.
>
> **Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea.**
>
> Passing through a **specific flag** in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.

So, consider passing an additional flag in the options and check that flag in your event listener to ignore what you do not need.

Check this [Jsbin Example](http://jsbin.com/jotuturi/1/edit?js,console)

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults: { a: 5 } });
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: M });

var c = new C();
var m = new M({a:1});

c.on('add', function(model, collection, options) { 
  console.log(options); 
  if (!options.flag) { return; }
});

c.add(m, {flag: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
collection.add({name: 'xyz'}, {silent: true});
```